# Combo Box is not observed

Tags: javafx-8

I have the following Code:

```
public class GuiView extends Application {

  private ObservableList<String> shareNames = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

  public void start(Stage stage) {
    ...
    ComboBox<String> comboBox = new ComboBox<String>();
    comboBox.getItems().addAll(this.shareNames);

    MenuItem open = new MenuItem("Open...");
    open.setOnAction( e -> {
      // FileChooser code...
      if (selctedFile != null) {
        this.shareNames.addAll("teststring");
      }
    });
  }
}
```

When I run through the open dialog successfully the combo box doesn't update and shows the teststring. What is going wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are updating `shareNames`, but that is not the list used by the combo box.

Either replace

```
comboBox.getItems().addAll(this.shareNames);
```

with

```
comboBox.setItems(this.shareNames);
```

or replace

```
this.shareNames.addAll("teststring");
```

with

```
comboBox.getItems().add("teststring");
```